# Files not waiting for each other

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have two batch files as follows in which **file2.bat** is dependent on **file1.bat**'s output:

**file1.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "keystring1="
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
Source.txt
 ) DO (
ECHO %%a|FIND "Appprocess.exe" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
FOR %%b IN (App1 App2 App3 App4 App5 App6 ) DO (
ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET  "keystring1="

)))>result.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

**file2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (memory.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('find " %%a " ^< result.txt ') do echo %%c %%b
))> new.txt
```

**file1.bat** usually takes 60 sec to complete its execution.

In **master.bat** file i am calling above two files as:

```
call file1.bat
call file2.bat
```

but **file2.bat** is not waiting for **file1.bat** to complete its execution.

Even , i tried to call **file2.bat** within **file1.bat** as below but still its not waiting for **file1.bat** to get completed:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "keystring1="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  Source.txt
  ) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FIND "HsvDataSource.exe" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
  FOR %%b IN (EUHFMPROD USHFMPROD TL2TEST GSHFMPROD TL2PROD GSARCH1213 TL2FY13) DO (
   ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET    "keystring1="

  )))>file2.txt

GOTO :EOF

call file1.bat
```

I also tried below **start** option, but no effect.:

```
start file1.bat /wait
call file2.bat
```

Not getting ..why its happening..?

Comment: As I posted in my comment below, with the files you have posted it is **not possible** for `file2.bat` to run before `file1.bat` has completed.  Ergo you are misinterpreting the problem or you haven't posted the real batch files.  There are no commands in `file1.bat` above that are multi-threaded.

Comment: Just supossing. If your real code is what you have posted, the problem could be the path to the files. There is no path indication anywhere. When you run your batch files scheduled, the current dir is probably not the dir of the batch files and "maybe" batch files or data files are not found because they are generated in another place?

Comment: @foxidrive..got the error..actually source.txt (input for file1.bat) was getting updated while file1.bat started to call it..i added a ~20sec **ping** delay between source.txt creation and file1.bat calling to it..and thus it resolved the issue completely..thank u foxi..!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you see is probably not quite as you describe it.

Run this, when you see the pause prompt then examine `result.txt` to see what is inside it.

If the contents of `result.txt` are correct then hit a key and allow file2.bat to run.  See if it runs correctly.

If it fails then capture the error messages on the console and tell us what is in `result.txt` and `new.txt`

```
call file1.bat
pause
call file2.bat
pause
```

Comment: @Foxidrive..in above way..its working correctly , but after removing **pause** in between files call..its not working..moreover FYI..in **master.bat** i have total 9 batch files to call Foxi..all are working correctly.but this file1.bat which tales maximum time..is destroying all..because other files are dependent on its output.

Comment: & another point is to run **master.bat** in invisible/hidden mode..i am using below VB Script: 
'Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\master.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing'

Comment: With the files you have posted it is **not possible** for `file2.bat` to run before `file1.bat` has completed.  Ergo you are misinterpreting the problem or you haven't posted the real batch files.

Answer (score 3):

I can't confirm your observation. Please look at the session screen:

[image]

Comment: @Endoro..in **master.bat** i have total 9 batch files using call dependent on one- other's output to. all are working correctly.but this file1.bat which tales maximum time..is destroying all..because other files are dependent on its output..& another point is to run master.bat in invisible/hidden mode..i am using below VB Script: 'Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\master.bat" & Chr(34), 0 Set WshShell = Nothing'

Comment: @Sunny   it doesn't depend on the number of calls but only on their sequence.

Comment: @Endoro..m exhausted on why its not working for me..:(..is there any way to add 70 sec wait time between file1.bat and file2.bat..?

Comment: @Sunny   yes: `ping -n 71 localhost>nul` **or** `timeout /t 70`.

Comment: @Endoro..i used ping delay method to insert delay between source.txt creation and file1.bat calling to it..because source.txt (input for file1.bat) was getting updated while file1.bat started to call it. .thanks for your help..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. How do you know that the problem you have is what you think? There is a very easy way to test it. Insert the following line in `master.bat` before calling `file1.bat`:

```
echo "master.bat" started at %time% > logfile.txt
```

And insert the following line at beginning of each one of the nine Batch files:

```
echo "%~NX0" started at %time% >> logfile.txt
```

**EDIT**: And insert the following line at end of each one of the nine Batch files:

```
echo "%~NX0" ended at %time% >> logfile.txt
```

Then run your program and post the contents of `logfile.txt` please...

Comment: @Aacini..yes..it worked for me..actually **source.txt** was causing all problems..now its smoothly running..thanks..!:)